# I am calling an ASMX web service from javascript and it is preveting my session from timing out

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, session

**EDIT 2:**

I have a background process running on the server side based on a schedule or an end user's request, and i need to show an image to all the users to keep him notified that this process is running, or take out the image when the process is finished.

**EDIT 2 Finished**

I am calling an ASMX web service which is located in my website hosted on my IIS from javascript and it is preveting my session from timing out.

Why does a call from the client to the webservice prevent the session on my website to timeout ?

Is there a way to prevent it ?

Please tell me if you need more clarity in my question or more details.

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the information and the [link](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/asp-net-mvc-avoid-resetting-the-form-authentication-cookie-timeout-for-a-request/#comment-252) provided by @Rene147 in the answer below as well as some googling, i tried the following on the side of my webservice :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=false)]
public string GetSummary()
{           
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    return "something";
}
```

But it turns out that `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies` is always empty.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Forms Authentication uses Sliding Expiration.  This means that each time you make a request to the server your cookies expiration is reset (with some caveats).

To disable Sliding Expiration set "slidingExpiration" in your web.config to false. Taken from [Sliding Expiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    requireSSL="true" 
    slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: In the application this property is not set at all.
But setting this property to false, how will this affect the behavior of the application and the interaction between end-users and the pages ?

Comment: By default slidingExpiration is set to "True". Because the expiration is no long sliding even if the user is interacting with the website once the TimeOut (I think the default timeout is 30mins) expires they will be logged out of the site.

Comment: But i don't want that to apply to my website, is there any way to make the ajax calls to my ASMX web services and not affecting the session timeout,but also without affecting the timeout policy of the users interacting with the website.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Your user is geting / posting to your server within an AJAX call just like they are in a normal postback.  The cookie will continue to be updated regardless of how the request was made.  You "could" possibly implement your own auth provider that takes AJAX into account but thats not going to be simple.  Or if your using MVC you might be able to do this with some kind of filter?

Comment: I am using asp.net webforms. Do you have an example of how to start implementing my own auth provider ? Or else, do you have any suggestions in which i can poll the server from my client without affecting the session timeout ?

Comment: Sorry you'll have to google it.  I did however find this http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/asp-net-mvc-avoid-resetting-the-form-authentication-cookie-timeout-for-a-request/ might give you a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of your last edit - if you want to read cookie's value, you need to use **Context.Request.Cookies** instead of **Response**.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public string GetSummary()
{
    HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
        Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    return "something";
}
```

Comment: There is no cookie in my request either by the requested name.
I was hoping, i could find a solution for the problem mentioned in my question by prohibiting the server for sending back the FormsAuthentication cookie from my web service, do youhave anything in mind ?